# How to get value from another model and save on current record

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I'm using cakephp 2.1 and Wamp and it's all good. I need to get a value (not the id field) from one model (project) and assign it to the record being saved (setup), something like:

SetupsConstroller.php

```
$this->request->data['Setup']['client_id'] = $this->Setup->$projects['Project']['client_id'];
```

model setup.php

```
var $belongsTo = array('Client', 'User', 
        'Project' => array(
                'className' => 'Project',
                'foreignKey' => 'pr_number'
                )
        );
```

In my SetupsController I get the projects:

```
$projects = $this->Setup->Project->find('list', array(
        'order' => 'name',
        'foreignKey' => 'pr_number',
        'fields' => array('Project.pr_number', 'Project.name'),
        'conditions' => array('pr_status' => 2)
            ));
```

So when adding the setup, I get pr_number from $projects, all good:

add.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->input('pr_number', array('label' => 'ASC Project:', 'options' => $projects));
```

Now, what I need is another value (client_id) from the projects record, and assign it to a column on my setups model being saved. Something like I did to assign the current user_id just before saving:

SetupsController.php (add function)

```
$this->request->data['Setup']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id'); // this works fine

// Next line needs fixing, returns NULL, Don't know how to access client_id from projects model!
$this->request->data['Setup']['client_id'] = $this->Setup->$projects['Project']['client_id'];

        if ($this->Setup->save($this->request->data)) { // then save
```

Tried 
    loadModule 
and other suggestions but no luck.

I don’t think this is that uncommon?

Can anyone help?

Thank you so much.

Carlos from Tijuana, México

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Setup belongsTo Project`:

```
$selectedProjectId = $this->request->data['Setup']['pr_number'];

$client_id = $this->Setup->Project->find
    (
        'first',
        array
        (
            'recursive' => -1,
            'fields' => array('Project.client_id'),
            'conditions' => array('Project.pr_number' => $selectedProjectId)
        )
    );

// something like this should work
$this->request->data['Setup']['client_id'] = $client_id['Project']['client_id'];
```

But, I'm typing this code without testing, so it may not work on the first try. If it's not, do this to see what you got:

```
debug($client_id); // it should be here
```

On the other hand, copying your fields in the database like that could indicate a problem with your database design.

Comment: Thx !. The part I don't get is `$yourCurrentSetupId` .. I tried getting the current with `$this->request->data['Setup']['id']` but it doesn't work.   As for the database design, you are right, this copied field is only put there "just in case" since the setup is tied to the project via belongsTo. Still, I don't want to leave that field empty, I know I'll need it later.   Thanks !, hope you can help.   Carlos

Comment: @CarlosGarcia: Are you adding a new `Setup` here or editing an existing one? If you're adding a new one, you'll have to change the query to run on `$this->Setup->Project` and conditions to `Project.id` (I'm assuming you have project id available?). Let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hannibal, I'm adding a new Setup. When adding a Setup, user picks a Project from a list; project.pr_number is stored ok on my new setup, but I also need another field, project.client_id to save with my new Setup.  I'm really coming to terms with cake. Would you be kind enough to udpate the answer if possible?     Thanks !!!  Carlos

Comment: @CarlosGarcia: Sorry about the late reply. I hope the above works, but if not, post your code and the errors, and we'll investigate further ;)

Comment: It works just fine. Thank you so much, I really appreciate and feel motivated to keep on learning this tool. Thanks again.

Comment: @CarlosGarcia: Glad I could help :) To say thanks the "stackoverflow way", mark the answer as accepted on the left side, just below the voting icons. This will also help anyone else facing the same problem as you to recognize the correct answer immediately.